# My grub is gone after update to ubuntu 13. I get a grub prompt on boot how do I get back?

Tags: boot, grub2, updates

I have found different posts here that deal with similar issues, but I am unable to get any of these to work. Here is what happened to me:

I had an ubuntu-12 installation, on which I ran update and upgrade (clicked on the update button on the task bar). After this, the machine rebooted, and I noticed that the task bar still had the intimation for update. After clicking this a second time, the machine asked to reboot, and after rebooting I am at the bare grub prompt. Here is what I have tried so far.

I tried to see if I could boot from the menu (according to another post here.) But my grub menu was wiped.

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
-- This is empty
```

Next, I tried to find the vmlinuz partition using 'find' but apparently, 'find' does not exist any more. I see a command 'help' which scrolls fast, and I don't see any way to look at any thing more than the last screen full. (no more/less commands)

Any way, I found another post mentioning 'ls', using which I found that my partition (hd0,msdos5) contains my ubuntu installation.

```
prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
insmod (hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub/linux.mod
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda5 ro
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

And various combinations there of, by removing ro, removing prefix etc. I get the following screen

```
VFS: Can not open root device "sda5" or unknown-block(0,0)
Please append a correct root= boot option; here are the available partitions (empty)
Kernel panic - VFS unable to mount root fs on unnown-block(0,0)
```

Now, what do I try next? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best bet is to try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It will reinstall Grub for you. From there you can continue to repair your system if the upgrade failed.